# VIM - Fastest way to yank an awkward text block

Tags: vim, editor, text-editor, vi

I am using VIM 7.1.314 and would like to yank the names `(chris, robert, ben)` in the code shown below as fast as possible - how would I achieve this? Note the names are always aligned (regardless of users number).

```
user 1: chris (05/04/1984)
user 2: robert (11/12/1991)
user 3: ben (5/25/1993)
```

Also note, I'm looking for a solution where there is hundreds of names so scalability is important.

Comment: What do you want to do with the names?  Something like `cut` or `sed` might work better depending on what you want to do.

Comment: paste them into another vim editor as keys for a hash :) - also the names are always alphanumeric with no spaces

Comment: Do you know the length of the longest name (or at least a limit on it)?

Comment: @Jeremiah: No more than 16 characters

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An easy way to do this is to shell out to an external program to help. For example:

```
:%!awk '{ print $3 }'
```

That will replace your entire edit buffer with the results of running that `awk` command on the contents of the current buffer. You can then copy the result to another file or whatever, and `u` easily gets your original buffer back to its previous state.

Comment: Hi, thanks for response, this does answer my initial question well - but I should have been more specific - the items there are just embedded in other text. I'm just searching for a fast way to yank a column of words all anchored at the same column but having different lengths

Answer (score 3):

Given that your names are not going to be longer than 16 characters, use a regex search and replace to add 16 spaces after each name, then use block visual mode to do the copy.  First, do (on the command line):

```
:%s/: [^ ]*/&                /
```

That blank area is 16 spaces.  Then, go to the start of the first name and press `Control-V`, then go 15 characters to the right and to the last line of the list of names and press `Y` to copy, then to your destination buffer and press `P` to paste.

Comment: Thanks, This worked great - I was really hoping that I could do something like block-visual select the first letter of each name then do yw to copy all the words :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a plugin called Tabularize which you can get from https://github.com/godlygeek/tabular. In the case you listed you could do

```
 :Tabularize /(.*
```

and it will change your text file to look like this:

```
user 1: chris  (05/04/1984)
user 2: robert (11/12/1991)
user 3: ben    (5/25/1993)
```

Then you can simply use visual block to pull the text. It's a great plugin that saves an incredible amount of time.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pure viml solution that leaves the original buffer unchanged:

```
:let names= []
:g/^user \d/let names+= matchstr(getline('.'), 'user \d\+:\s*\zs\S\+')
:new
:put=names
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use macros.

1. `qeq`   (to clear the "e" register)
2. `qa03w"Eywjq`    (to register a macro yanking the name)
3. `200000@a`     (repeat the macro a lots of time)

And then your names are in the "e" register. Type "ep to view them !

Notes :

- maybe the `yw` is not correct, maybe a yt( or something, depending on names.
- `:set lazyredraw` can help with macro performance !